# How to Run HTA in hidden mode

Tags: hta

I have an HTA file which works perfectly well, but my problem is that i will like the HTA console to be hidden when the file runs.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 3000);
function myTimer() {
    objShell=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
objShell.Run ('%windir%\\System32\\cmd.exe /c %temp%\\readme.txt', 0);window.close();
}
</script>
```

Without the timer, it runs hidden, but when i include the timer it shows the console.

Can someone help me fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You have some options; you can use windowstate="minimize" in you HTA attributes see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176567.aspx for more info about the attributes.

The app will still be shown on the taskbar while it runs so you can set showintaskbar to **no** but then you will see the window minimized small in the corner of the screen.

You can use `window.resizeTo(0,0);` with `WINDOWSTATE="normal"` but there will be a flicker of the window before it changes size.

You can experiment with the options and see which one best suits your needs.

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
        APPLICATIONNAME="myApp"
        WINDOWSTATE="normal"
        MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
        MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
        CAPTION="no"
        SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
        >
        <script>
            window.resizeTo(0,0);
            var myVar = setInterval(function(){ myTimer() }, 3000);
            function myTimer() {
                objShell=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
            objShell.Run ('%windir%\\System32\\cmd.exe /c %temp%\\readme.txt', 0);window.close();
            }
        </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY SCROLL="no">
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just opening a text file, why bother with the command prompt? Also, why is there an interval if the HTA just closes right after the file is opened? I think you should be able to just do the following, while also using the `WINDOWSTATE` property as suggested by Gordon:

```
objShell.Run("%temp%\\readme.txt", 0, true);
window.close();
```